# Get Object from List<Object> if a particular field in Object matches any value from a separate list

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of strings like under which contains all the store Numbers:

```
List<String> stores = new ArrayList<>;
```

And a List of Objects like:

```
List<UserStores> userStores = new ArrayList<>;
```

Now, this UserStores class looks something like this:

```
public class UserStores {
    
    private String storeNo;
    private String storeName;
    private String country;
}
```

I want to get all the UserStores from this `List<UserStores>` if any of the storeNo is present in the 'stores' List given above.

For example,

```
stores = {1,2};
UserStores = [ {2, qwe, wqew}, {1,ABC, India}, {3, asd, USA} ];

expected result = [{1,ABC, India}, {2, qwe, wqew}]; in the order of stores present in 'stores' list,
```

How can I get this using stream/collectors?

My current code is something like this..can this be improved?

```
private static List<UserStores> getModifiedUserStoresList(
            List<String> stores, List<UserStores> userStores
    ) {
        List<UserStores> userStoreList = new ArrayList<>();
        
       
        for(int i = 0; i < stores.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < userStores.size(); j++) {
                if(userStores.get(j).getStoreNo().equals(stores.get(i))) {
                    userStoreList.add(userStores.get(j));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return userStoreList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain proper order and keep duplicates, a map `Map<String, UserStores>` should be created first (e.g. using `Collectors.toMap`), and then `stores` should be streamed and mapped by appropriate keys:

```
private static List<UserStores> getModifiedUserStoresList(
        List<String> stores, List<UserStores> userStores
) {
    Map<String, UserStores> map = userStores.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserStores::getStoreNo, us -> us, (a, b) -> a));
        
    return stores.stream()
        .filter(map::containsKey)
        .map(map::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Streams API and filter the list of UserStores:

```
List<UserStores> filtered = userStores.stream()
    .filter(u -> stores.contains(u.getStoreNo()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wonder if the sorting order that the question is asking for is guaranteed here.

Comment: @SreeKumar There's no sorting order in the question, however you can sort streams using the `sorted(Comparator)` method on the stream

Comment: There is this line in the listing containing the expected result: `in the order of stores present in 'stores' list`. Hence, the sorting point. Also, `sorted(Comparator)` may be cumbersome because of the nature of the sorting requested.

Comment: When `stores = {1,1}` in the OP code, the result contains two duplicated elements. But yours is one element.

Comment: OK, @Manulaiko, I see the following in the JavaDocs of `Collectors.toList()`: "**Returns:** a Collector which collects all the input elements into a List, **in encounter order**". Also, I see that `toList()` uses an `ArrayList` which maintains insertion order. Hence, this answer should work without specific sorting.

Comment: @Manulaiko this won't maintain the sorting order because this code checks whether the first userStore no. is there in the stores' list or not. And if present, it just adds that in encounter order and not in the order of the stores list.